# AngularJs ng-click fires twice on enter button press

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have a form with the following buttons:

```
<form name="invoiceLine">
  <div class="rTableRow">
    <div class="rTableCell rTableCellXsm" ng-keyup="keyPress($event)">{{invoice_line.line}}</div>
    <div class="rTableCell rTableCellL" >
      <datecomponent style="display: inline-block" model="invoice_line.date" elementid="il2" tabindex="'1'"></datecomponent>
    </div>
    <div class="rTableCell rTableCellXl" ng-keyup="keyPress($event)">
      <input id="invLineDesc" style="width: 90%;" type="text" ng-model="invoice_line.description" ng-maxlength="30" tabindex="2">
      <span class="redtext">*</span>
    <div>{{invoice_line.description.length <= 30 ? 30 - invoice_line.description.length + ' chars remaining' : 'Description too long!' }}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="rTableCell rTableCellL" ng-keyup="keyPress($event)">
      $<input style="width: 50%; margin-left: 5px;" type="text" ng-model="invoice_line.amount" tabindex="3">
     </div>
     <div class="rTableCell rTableCellL">
       <input type="button" class="button {{buttonPrefColor}}" ng-click="add_new_invoice_line()" ng-show="invoiceLine.$dirty" value="Add New" tabindex="4">
       <input type="button" class="button {{buttonPrefColor}}" ng-click="reset_invoice_line_btn()" ng-show="invoiceLine.$dirty" value="Reset" tabindex="5">
     </div>
   </div>
 </form>
```

However if I tab over to the `Add New` Button and hit "Enter" then it calls the ng-click function twice. If I click it, it only triggers once. Any ideas?

Comment: can you provide plunkr?

Comment: This is unusual. However, it's hard to help without a demo in this case, because otherwise it's not reprodusable.

Comment: For the most part I am looking to see if anyone else has seen this and might know what it is. I'm not about to recreate my gigantic project in plunkr unfortunately. If you want some more code examples I can provide them but I can't spend hours reproducing in plunkr

Comment: that attitude of "I'm not about to recreate my project to show you what the problem is" will not help you to find anyone interested in helping you find a solution.  unless you can demonstrate the issue in a reproducible form, the only thing anyone can do is make blind, wild guesses at the problem.

Comment: You need to show the entire form (at least the form tag if you are using `ng-submit`, and any buttons that are in the form -- in particular this relates to Angular looking for a button w/type="submit" ... and it starts to guess when it can't find that). The problem is likely caused by how Angular tries to figure out which is the "submit" button on your form when you press the enter key.

Comment: Sunil D I think you actually hit the nail on the head. I will add the rest of the form but I believe its firing off twice because its submitting the form and firing the ng-click...will update question soon.

Comment: NM I looked it over and I don't see why `add_new_invoice_line` would be called twice....

Comment: Claies the whole mentality of having to recreate your entire issue in plunkr is absurd. Most of the time people are coming to stackoverflow for a quick answer on their question because they dont have the TIME to spend hours and hours debunking their code and hope someone may have seen the same thing you are seeing. To then tell them to spend those hours and hours recreating their issue in plunkr is kind of against the point. I realize plunkr can make simple issues easy to answer but in the case of a HUGE project like mine..not so much. Thanks for the downvote

Comment: Agreeing with Claies here. Besides, this is clearly not a problem caused by a "HUGE project".

Comment: hey look Sunil D. was able to answer it without a plunkr....the world continues spinning

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Checkout the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form#submitting-a-form-and-preventing-the-default-action) for the `form` directive, it has some rules on what Angular does when you press enter on a form:

> To prevent double execution of the handler, use only one of the ngSubmit or ngClick directives. This is because of the following form submission rules in the HTML specification:
>
> If a form has only one input field then hitting enter in this field triggers form submit (ngSubmit)
>
> If a form has 2+ input fields and no buttons or input[type=submit] then hitting enter doesn't trigger submit
>
> If a form has one or more input fields and one or more buttons or input[type=submit] then hitting enter in any of the input fields will trigger the click handler on the first button or input[type=submit] (ngClick) and a submit handler on the enclosing form (ngSubmit)

I think there are several ways you could fix it, but this might be the least hackish:

Remove the `ng-click` handler from the button, and use `ng-submit` on the form instead:

```
<form name="myForm" ng-submit="add_new_invoice_line()">
...
<button type="submit">Add New</button>
</form>
```

Other ideas:

- Remove the `<form>` tag all together. Unless you want to use Angular's form validation features.
- Try adding a hidden button before the "Add New" button, so that Angular finds that one when you press enter.